# PHP: Save recipe: how to retrieve recipe name from previous page (it's in a table) and store in a php variable?

Tags: php, mysqli, save

What I am trying to do is retrieve the recipe name from the previous page so I can use it in an SQL query.

The code to display the table is below:

```
$query = "SELECT `recipe_name`, `recipe_price`, `recipe_calories`, `recipe_fat`, `recipe_cholestrol`, `recipe_carbs`, `recipe_protein`, `recipe_fibre`, `recipe_sodium`, `recipe_potassium`, `recipe_source`
FROM `carbohydrates` WHERE `ingredient_name`= 'bananas' AND recipe_id = 1";
$data= mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1' width='100%'>
<tr>
<th>Recipe Name</th>
<th>Recipe Price</th>
<th>Recipe Calories</th>
<th>Amount of Fat</th>
<th>Amount of Cholestrol</th>
<th>Amount of Carbs</th>
<th>Amount of Protein</th>
<th>Amount of Fibre</th>
<th>Amount of Sodium</th>
<th>Amount of Potassium</th>
<th>Recipe Source</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['recipe_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['recipe_price'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['recipe_calories'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['recipe_fat'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['recipe_cholestrol'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['recipe_carbs'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['recipe_protein'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['recipe_fibre'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['recipe_sodium'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['recipe_potassium'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><a href=\"" . $row['recipe_source'] . "\">Click here to view the recipe</a></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

$recipe_name = $row['recipe_name'];

echo $recipe_name;
```

The code to save the recipe (so far):

if (!isset($_SESSION['recipe_id'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

```
    $query = "SELECT `recipe_id` FROM `carbohydrates` WHERE `recipe_name` = \"banana bread\"";

    $data= mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {

        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data);
        $_SESSION['recipe_id'] = $row['recipe_id'];
         setcookie('recipe_id', $row['recipe_id'], time() + (60 * 60 * 24 * 30));    // expires in 30 days

     }

     echo $_SESSION['recipe_id'];

     }
 }
```

So for the SQL query above, I want to use '$recipe_name' instead of using the actual name of the recipe (this does work but I want to be able to use this code for other recipes not just one)

Thanks for all the help in advance,

Sarah

Comment: Did you used session_start()

Comment: on the save_recipe page I have

Answer (score -1):

Use session_start() on both pages.

To save $recepie in session use

```
$_SESSION['recepie'] = $recepie;
```

and on page where use want to use $recepie
start the session using session_start() and the fetch it using

```
if(isset($_SESSION['recepie']))
$recepie = $_SESSION['recepie']);
```

Comment: thanks for that Undefined_variable. I added session_start () to the page where the table is displayed and also changed this:

Comment: $recipe_name = $row['recipe_name'];

$_SESSION['recipe_name'] = $recipe_name;

echo $recipe_name;

Comment: can you tell which page executes first top or below

Comment: the top page executes first

Comment: Did you add session_start() and $_SESSION['recipe_name'] = $recipe_name; on that page

Comment: Also did you add if(isset($_SESSION['recepie_name']))
$recepie = $_SESSION['recepie_name']); on second page

Comment: yes i did, i added session_start() at the top of the page and then below the code for the table i added $_SESSION['recipe_name'] = $recipe_name